# system of differential equations with matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

$x′ = Ax$

where $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
3&1&0\\
0&3&0\\
0&0&2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
what is the logic to solve such type of equations?

I found that $det(A-λI) = (3-λ)^2(2-λ)=0$, so the eigenvalues are 3 and 2

Comment: My favorite way? Eigenstuff (eigenvalues and eigenvectors).

Comment: What do you mean you found the characteristic polynomial? The matrix is already in Jordan form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full process requires these steps:

- Compute the characteristic polynomial and find the eigenvalues, say $\lambda, \mu, \nu$. I'll assume theses eigenvalues are distinct, so the matrix is diagonalisable in a basis of eigenvectors.
- Find a basis of eigenvectors, say $u,v,w$. Let  $P$ be the change of basis matrix from the canonical basis to this basis of eigenvectors.
- In this basis, the matrix $A$ takes the form $\;\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&0&0\\0&\mu&0\\0&0&\nu\end{bmatrix}$, hence the  exponential is
  $$\exp(A't)=\begin{bmatrix}\mathrm e^{\lambda t}&0&0\\0&\mathrm e^{\mu t}&0\\0&0&\mathrm e^{\nu t}\end{bmatrix}$$
- The relation between $A$ and $A'$ is : $\;A'=P^{-1}AP$, whence $\;A=PA'P^{-1}$, and similarly
  $$ \exp(At)=P\exp(A't)P^{-1}. $$

*If the matrix is not diagonalisable*:

- You have to find a *Jordan basis*. In such a basis, the matrix takes the form
  $$D+N=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&0&0\\0&\mu&0\\0&0&\nu\end{bmatrix}+N,$$
  where $\lambda, \mu,\nu$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $N$ is a *nilpotent matrix*.
- Now the exponential of a nilpotent matrix is easy to compute:  if $r$ is the index of nilpotency of $N$ (it is at most the dimension of the matrix), then
  $$\exp Nt=I+Nt+\frac{N^2}2t^2+\dots+\frac{N^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}t^{k-1}$$
- And finally we have 
  $$\exp(At)=P\bigl(\exp(Dt)\exp(Nt)\bigr)P^{-1}.$$

Comment: no, this type of matrix can't be diagonalisable

Comment: You mean *this*  matrix, I guess. *Per se* it has nothing special until you make the calculations. OK, I'll what to be done in this case.

Comment: yes, this. It can't be diagonalisable because number of eigenvectors is less than 3

Comment: I've added the steps for a non-diagonalisable matrix. Do you know the Jordan normal form?

Comment: yes, in my case it will be \begin{pmatrix}
3&0&0\\
0&3&0\\
0&0&2
\end{pmatrix}right?

Comment: There's an error. See my last comment to your question.

Comment: it will be $(3-λ)^2(2-λ)$

Comment: OK. Now you have to find the Jordan normal form and a *Jordan basis*.

Comment: \begin{pmatrix}
2&0&0\\
0&3&1\\
0&0&3
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Wolfram writes that it is the true

Comment: @themaker: I beg your pardon: they don't  commute? Which matrices are you speaking of?

Comment: I'm sorry: they do commute. Is it you who down voted?

Comment: $N=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ when right multiplied by the diagonal matrix has its *columns* multiplied by $2,3,3$. When it's left multiplied, its *lines* are multiplied by the same numbers, and you think it doesn't  yield the same result?

Comment: @themaker the diagonal matrix commutes with its nilpotent block always. This is really elementary.

Comment: Just read about the Jordan form before you downvote

Answer (score 1):

The *logic* is the same as to solve the ''scalar'' ordinary differential equation 
$
\frac{dx}{dt}=ax
$
that, with the initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ has the solution $x(t)=x_0e^{at}$.

For a ''vector'' equation $\frac{d\vec x}{dt}=A\vec x$ we have the solution $\vec x(t)=e^{At}\vec x(0)$.

Where the exponential of the matrix $A$ is defined as you can see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential).

Comment: could you be so kind to show exact steps?

Comment: See the answer of  Bernard ( +1)!